# Wordpress - Category list according to date (newest at the top)

Tags: wordpress, list, sorting, categories

I have tried searching but could not find a solution for this.

I was to list the categories but it has to be sorted according to the date that they were added. Newest added category should be at the top while the oldest should be at the bottom.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'order'              => 'DESC',
); ?>
 <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

This will work for you as whenever we create a new category or post is picks up a higher ID automatically, so greater the ID newest is the category created..

For instance, say you created a category on 2nd Oct, 2012 -> Category 1 - It will have say ID 21,
and you created a new category on 3rd Oct, 2012 -> Category 2 - Automatically it will have ID greater than 21